# Encrypt Json Payload using public Key (.cer)

Tags: swift, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Hi I want to encrypt Json Payload using public key that is .cer file. Please suggest how to do this?

```
  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Keys123_1", ofType: "cer")
 //get the data asociated to this file
        let urlStt =  URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        if let base64String = try? Data(contentsOf: urlStt).base64EncodedString() {
            print(base64String)

        let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: base64String)

        let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048),
            kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as NSObject
        ]
            var error:Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil


            guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(data2 as! CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, &error) else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
```

I am getting this error :

```
Optional(Swift.Unmanaged<__ObjC.CFError>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "RSA public key creation from data failed" UserInfo={NSDescription=RSA public key creation from data failed}))
```

Comment: Post your sample code, which you have tried so far. Also explain which algorithm you are using for encryption - decryption.

Comment: post your code in question not in answer, otherwise other will confuse, whether this is question or answer.

Comment: I have Public key (.cer) file we have to use AES algorithm  for encrypt I am very new in cryptography so please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Please, do not write cryptographic code! Cryptography is hard. Use a library which will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and encrypt with public key and verify data by decrypt with private key on server side. I followed this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption).

May be this work for you.

```
func getPublicKey() -> SecKey? {

        let certificateData = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "public", withExtension: "cer")!)

        let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData as CFData)
        var trust: SecTrust?

        let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
        let status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certificate!, policy, &trust)

        if status == errSecSuccess {
            let publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust!)!
            return publicKey
        }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certificateData as CFData)
 
certificate is coming nil

Comment: This is just working for me and tried from link I shared of Apple Document. Make sure that path is proper and you are getting certificateData from path.

Comment: You can also try `der` format in place of `cer` format.